# Letter O considered harmful?

Tags: history

Back in the day, the FORTRAN standards committee reviewed a technical proposal called "Letter O considered harmful". I used to be able to find a link to the text of this proposal on the net, but it seems to have disappeared since the last time I looked for it -- the link disappeared off the relevant Wikipedia page and the only Google hits for the term are references back to Wikipedia. Does anyone happen to know a good repository of information about FORTRAN so that I could track it down, or even better, have a link to the proposal itself?

Comment: never heard of that. is it because it can be easily mistaken for 0?

Comment: @Claudiu Among other things, yes. It was also suspect because programmers could write GOTO statements using that letter.

Comment: Why the downvote? Esoteric, but valid question, and not the "I wonder x, can you ask google for me?" kind.

Comment: @Claudiu: I once had a teacher who said he'd once spent several hours tracking down a bug caused by exactly this problem (he'd mistyped a 0 for an o in a variable name).

Comment: @Cameron Yeah, I believe especially in those old text editors, I remember the Borland Pascal editor making a clear difference between a zero and the letter O. @estanford GOTO statements, don't know if that's a joke or not, but definetly something good to avoid

Comment: @Claudiu The author meant it as a joke -- definitely one of the more amusing parts of the proposal. It's up there with Stan Ulam's inter-office memo with an alphabetized list of numbers from one to one-hundred, presented to his employees for ease of reference.

Comment: That was an internal joke back in the days, in the commitee. I can't believe this is being taken seriously. Btw, what has this got to do with fortran (where is the actual question relating to the fortran language)?

Comment: This is a joke that could be applied to any programming language.   I propose that the letter "I" be deleted from Java (randomly selected) become of its similarity to the numeral "1".

Comment: @Rook It's relevant to the FORTRAN language because the proposal showed up at a FORTRAN committee meeting. I figured that if anyone knows where to find the proposal or a repository of proposals from FORTRAN's historical, record, it would be people familiar with the FORTRAN language.

Comment: @estanford - <c/p> what M. S. B. said ...

Comment: @M.S.B. See? If we ban all characters, we can get rid of bad code forever! ;-) I'm mainly interested in finding the proposal for historical reasons, though. It's an important piece of FORTRAN folklore that looks like it may disappear from the record, and maybe already has.

Comment: @estanford - Then tag it under "folklore" - not under "fortran". You don't see me tagging questions about things that came to my mind, while listening to my C/C++ class under "C/C++" tag, do you? It has nothing to do with the language, therefore ...

Comment: @Rook If there was something more like a folklore tag than "language-history", I would have used it -- I only have 400 points right now, so I can't create new tags. If there are more appropriate categories to use than the ones I did, I'd be happy to retag the question.

Comment: Here's the first reference on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fortran&diff=prev&oldid=154702644 ... Doesn't look like it has ever had a link.

Answer (score 6):

You are indeed correct!

Yes, there was such a proposal (entitled "Letter 'O' Considered Harmful")
in the official set of documents supplied to voting members at the November 1976 meeting of X3J3 that was held at Brookhaven National Laboratory.  (At this same meeting, committee chose "Fortran 77", with six lower-case letters, as the name for this revision of the language.)

I am able to verify this because I was not only the host for this meeting but also the actual author of this anonymous "proposal".  As such, I enlisted the typist (my boss' secretary, Bette) to type up this phony "proposal" in the proper format and slip it into the official distribution provided at the meetingplace (Conference Room B of Berkner Hall).

Loren Meissner was so amused by it that he wrote a little item in a Fortran publication for which he was editor.  Walt Brainerd also mentioned it in his publication. I had sworn both of them to secrecy regarding my little prank, so those articles did not identify me. (Sorry, I don't recall the names of these two publications.)

The lists of pro and con arguments (as was typical of X3J3 proposals in those days) included:

- Restoring the number of Fortran characters to 48 (by omitting 'O'to counterbalance the addition of the colon ':')
- Solving ambiguities caused by nested DO loops.
- Eliminating problems with (deprecated) Hollerith specifications in FORMAT statements.
- Preventing misuse of GO TO statements.

while the "con" list contained only one objection (with a disclaimer):

- This proposal may invalidate some existing FORTRAN programs, but most of these are probably "standard-conforming" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the guy to ask: [Bruce A. Martin](http://abcdunlimited.com/bam/resume/resume.htm). He seems* to be the one who originally posted it on Wikipedia, and he puts himself as working at Brookhaven (where the article was circulated) at the same time.

The citation he gives on Wikipedia for the article is:

> X3J3 post-meeting distribution for meeting held at Brookhaven National Laboratory in November 1976.

(* the user page for the user that posted it links to the website as being their material)

Comment: This is a good lead. There's some suggestion on Open Standards (http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG5/3054) that the Letter O proposal may even have been written by him, or at least a proposal of the same name. I'm looking into it now.

Comment: Funnily enough, if you Google for "Letter o considered harmful" and restrict the search range to pre-2004, I get the result http://www.j3-fortran.org/ ... but I've yet to find any mention on the site :)

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#Letter_O_considered_harmful), referred to as a joke / folklore.  Doesn't surprise me TBH.

Comment: It does get mentioned on Wikipedia -- in multiple places, even -- but there used to be a link on the Wiki pages that went straight to the text of the proposal. That's the sort of thing I'm after.

Comment: @estanford Too bad Wikipedia doesn't keep a change history. Oh wai-

Comment: @bzlm I've been reviewing the change histories for a while now, but haven't had any luck. The last time I was able to find the link was years ago, so there's a lot of ground I need to cover to find the change.

Comment: I consider this most likely a joke/folklore. I can't recall it from the distant past (70's)

Comment: It was a tongue-and-cheek commentary on the great flowering of "X considered harmful" articles that came out after Dijkstra's original, as I recall. Someone submitted the article as a technical proposal that was read during the same committee session where the name FORTRAN77 was decided on.